# Getting "There is already an object named" while creating a temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QOTD, Line 12 There is already an object named '#tmpID3' in the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT) AS 
BEGIN 
  IF @source = 1 
    SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl1 
  ELSE 
    SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl2 

  SELECT ID FROM #tmpID3 

  DROP TABLE #tmpID3 
END
```

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QOTD, Line 7 There is already an object named '#tmpID3' in the database. – jesvin Nov 19 at 5:37

while adding this i am getting the error

Comment: This is a total shot in the dark, but I would *guess* that there is already an object named '#tmpID3` in the database.

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT)
AS 
BEGIN
 IF @source = 1 
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl1 
 ELSE
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl2 

 SELECT ID FROM #tmpID3
 DROP TABLE  #tmpID3
END

Comment: Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QOTD, Line 7
There is already an object named '#tmpID3' in the database.

Comment: while adding this i am getting the error

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing a *parser* error when trying to create your procedure. The temp table does not yet exist but the parser thinks it does.

Have a look at my answer to this question: [There is already an object named '#columntable' in the database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245444/there-is-already-an-object-named-columntable-in-the-database)

I originally thought, as others who have answered your question, that you would get this error because you were not explicitly dropping the temp table at the end of you procedure. However, as crokusek first pointed out in his comment:

> local temp tables are auto deleted at the end of the procedure in
>   which they are created

So I tried creating your procedure in my SQL Server 2008 instance and got the same error.

Changing the procedure to use different temp table names, as shown below, avoids the problem **and** proves the temp tables are dropped after the procedure ends.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 ( ID INT )
GO
CREATE TABLE tbl2 ( ID INT )
GO
INSERT INTO tbl1(ID) VALUES (1),(2),(3)
INSERT INTO tbl2(ID) VALUES (4),(5),(6)
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE QOTD ( @source INT )
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN 
        IF @source = 1 
            BEGIN
                SELECT  ID INTO #tmpID13 FROM tbl1
                SELECT  ID FROM #tmpID13
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT  ID INTO #tmpID23 FROM tbl2
                SELECT  ID FROM #tmpID23
            END
    END 
GO
EXEC QOTD 1
EXEC QOTD 2
```

Output:

```
ID
-----------
1
2
3

ID
-----------
4
5
6
```

Comment: The first part of your answer is not true (local temp tables are auto deleted at the end of the procedure in which they are created) so no difference if it called multiple times.  The second part of your answer is true--this is a parser error that happens sometimes when there are multiple select intos within an SP.  Your reference applies to a related problem but does not involve an SP.

Comment: @crokusek - Can you provide a reference to documentation regarding your claim that "local temp tables are auto deleted at the end of the procedure in which they are created"? I understood temp tables to be deleted when the _connection_ to the database they were created in is dropped.

Comment: Temp tables created at the session level only are session-bound.  All other temp tables are bound to the batch (stored procedure or other compilable unit) that created them.  Using SSMS tends to make this confusing because it's the only common way that Temp tables get created at the session level.

Comment: @crokusek - Thanks for your comment. I tested it out and have updated my answer to reflect the correct operation of temp tables in stored procedures.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - Thanks for your comment. I tested it out and have updated my answer to reflect the correct operation of temp tables in stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

It's already there. If you're creating this table as part of a regularly running script, add a DROP TABLE #tmpID3 at the start.

temp tables are single threaded (ie the server can do nothing else while creating it). If you're using it often, consider table variables instead.

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT)

AS 
BEGIN
 IF @source = 1 
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl1 
 ELSE
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl2 

 SELECT ID FROM #tmpID3
 DROP TABLE  #tmpID3
END

Comment: my error is here while inserting into it without even creating the temp table error occurs

Answer (score 0):

Start procedure QOTD with:

```
Drop Table #tmpID3
```

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT)

AS 
BEGIN
 IF @source = 1 
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl1 
 ELSE
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl2 

 SELECT ID FROM #tmpID3
 DROP TABLE  #tmpID3
END

Comment: while running this without even creating a temp table error is showing

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Check If Temporary Table Exists](http://sqlservercodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/check-if-temporary-table-exists.html)

**EDIT**  How to check for the temp table and drop it if it exists

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TEMP
END
```

**EDIT 2** It would seem that the 2 select into's are conflicting with each other. Creating the table before hand works though. Something like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpID3') IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 
        DROP TABLE #tmpID3 
    END
    CREATE TABLE #tmpID3(
            ID INT
    )
    IF @source = 1 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tmpID3 SELECT ID FROM tbl1 
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tmpID3 SELECT ID FROM tbl2
    END
    SELECT ID FROM #tmpID3 
    DROP TABLE #tmpID3 
END
```

**EDIT 3** the temp table is not required in this instance. A simple if will do

Something like

```
ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    IF @source = 1 
    BEGIN
        SELECT ID FROM tbl1 
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT ID FROM tbl2
    END
END
```

Comment: ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT)

AS 
BEGIN
 IF @source = 1 
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl1 
 ELSE
 SELECT ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl2 

 SELECT ID FROM #tmpID3
 DROP TABLE  #tmpID3
END

Comment: the problem is here without even creating a temp table it showing Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Procedure QOTD, Line 11
There is already an object named '#tmpID3' in the database.

Comment: Thats fine, so start the procedure by checking if it exists, and drop it if it does.

Comment: SO, then in the *IF EXISTS* step, *DROP TABLE #tmpID3*

Comment: I CAN DROP USING THE DROP TABLE STATEMENT

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you how to drop a temp table if it exists.

Comment: THEN I DROP IT USING THE PREVIOUS COMMENT

Comment: I have a problem if we creating without the temp table it will work correctly.

Comment: You do not need the temp table for what you are attempting. See my edited wnswer for details

Comment: actually this is a question that is asked in one of the site... so that i tried to answer it....like the way it look like...the site is http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Database+Design/70796/

Answer (score 0):

Objects have to have unique names across the database.  SQL Server handles the uniqueness of temporary table names.  However, if there are supplementary objects, such as separately created primary keys, it is possible for collisions to occur when two users attempt to create the table at the same time.

The error message you cite has an object with ID in its name, so I am guessing this is the situation you find yourself in.  Andy Novick has written a note on this topic, explaining why it might happen and giving a couple of workarounds.  [Check it out](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1763).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, see my answer here:
[There is already an object named '#columntable' in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245444/there-is-already-an-object-named-columntable-in-the-database#25563861)

The solution in this case seems to be to first create the table, then add the rows.  This way the parser does not complain (as this is a [known parser issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295305)).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE QOTD (@source INT) AS 
BEGIN
  -- Create the table without having to declare any column types or sizes
  SELECT TOP 0 ID INTO #tmpID3 FROM tbl1

  -- Prevent IDENTITY_INSERT error
  SET IDENTITY_INSERT #tmpID3 ON

  -- Add the actual rows required
  IF @source = 1 
    INSERT INTO INTO #tmpID3 (ID) SELECT ID FROM tbl1
  ELSE 
    INSERT INTO INTO #tmpID3 (ID) SELECT ID FROM tbl2

  SET IDENTITY_INSERT #tmpID3 OFF

  SELECT ID FROM #tmpID3 

  DROP TABLE #tmpID3 
END
```