# There is already an object named '#result' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
Alter Procedure sp_Member(
  @comcode int = 0,
  @SubComCode int = 0
)
as begin
  set nocount on
  If @comcode='0'
  begin
    select (
      select sum(amount)
        from tbcoudet
        where memcode=tbm.memcode and
              expyear=(select max(expyear) from tbexpyear)
              and exists (
                select itemcode
                from tbitem
                where comcode=@comcode and
                  SubComCode=@SubComCode and
                  itemcode=tbcoudet.itemcode
              )
        group by memcode,expyear
      )'TurnOver', *
    into #result from tbmember tbm where can_flag='N'
  end
  If @subcomcode='0'
  begin
    select (
      select sum(amount)
      from tbcoudet
      where memcode=tbm.memcode and expyear=(select max(expyear) from tbexpyear)
        and exists (
          select itemcode
          from tbitem
          where comcode=@comcode and
            itemcode=tbcoudet.itemcode
        )
      group by memcode,expyear
    )'TurnOver', *
    into #result from tbmember tbm where can_flag='N'
  end

  select top 10 * from #result where TurnOver is not null order by TurnOver desc
end
```

That is my sql code and when i am going to execute store procedure then I get the error

```
There is already an object named '#result' in the database.
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: The error is: there is already a temporary table by that name - don't re-create it if it already exists....

Comment: @ user1099310, use the tool box button `{}` for representing your code parts.

Answer (score 9):

The error is: there is already a temporary table by that name - don't re-create it if it already exists....

The problem lies in the way you do your select's - you have two places where you have

```
select (columns)
into #result 
from tbmember tbm 
...
```

The first time around, this will **create** the temporary table `#result`. And the second time around, you'll get the error - since it cannot create a table that already exists.

So you need to change your code to:

- explicitly create the table `#result` in the beginning

  ```
  CREATE TABLE #result ( ...give list of columns and their datatypes here .....)
  ```
- use code like this to insert values:

  ```
  INSERT INTO #result(colum list)
     SELECT (column list) 
     FROM  .......
     WHERE .......
  ```

That code will work and you will be able to insert two sets of data into your temporary table.

Comment: ...and don't forget `DROP TABLE #result` at the end!

Comment: @onedaywhen: temp tables like `#result` are automatically dropped when the session / connection ends (or if you create them inside a stored proc - when the stored proc ends). So if you use the "open as late as possible / close right away after use" principle of how to talk to SQL Server, when you close the connection, any local temp tables assigned to your session are discarded automatically

Comment: I like to make the intent clear. Also handy when copy+paste the contents of the proc into a new query window for testing etc. No biggie, of course ;)

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT ... INTO ...` always wants to create a ***new*** temp table.

Instead, create the temp table at the top of the procedure (using `create table #result (columns)`), and then re-write your selects using `INSERT INTO (columns) SELECT ...` instead.

I'm unable to write out a full example, since I don't know your column definitions.

Even if, as a matter of course, only *one* of your `if` statements is true, the T-SQL parser is rather simple, and still "sees" both attempted declarations of `#result`.

---

As an aside, I'm not sure why you're writing your `if` statements like this:

```
if @subcomcode='0'
```

Since `@subcomcode` is an int, you'd be better off not quoting the `0` literal.

Comment: Yes for the "...parser is rather simple part", because even if you sequentially drop, create, drop, create, this error still occurs in 2012.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not sure whether temp table exists or not but you are sure that before next statement you won't need it use [`object_id` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328) this way:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#result', 'u') is not null
    drop table #result
```

It will not cause an error if table doesn't exist and drop it if it does. In my opinion it's a good practice to use just before each:

```
select ... into #temp from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Agreed it's good to drop before creating new temp tables.  But a simple workaround is just to close your DB connection when debugging this type of stuff.  As the disconnection - wipes all those for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, but neither proposed solution here helps me. I have 6 ifs similar to this two in a stored procedure and it won't let me alter the procedure, which makes no sense, it clearly could work. Throws same error on alter procedure. I must have into #tbl in every if because every if has select with different columns and I don't want to make table for every select. Other option is dynamic selects...

I had to make it dynamic (not all), like this:

```
IF @Type = '1'
    SELECT
        col1
    INTO #tbl1
    FROM Table1
ELSE IF @Type = '2'
    SELECT
        col1
        ,col2
    INTO #tbl2
    FROM Table2
--IF...

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    select 
        *
    from #tbl' + @Type

EXEC (@sql)
```

But in your case, you should create temp table manually because you are using same structure and just adding value.

If you are lazy to create temp table with all the columns, another solution would be this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Member (
    @comcode INT = 0
  , @SubComCode INT = 0
  )
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON

  SELECT  CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), 0) TurnOver
        , *
  INTO    #result
  FROM    tbmember
  WHERE   can_flag = 'N'

  IF @comcode = '0'
  BEGIN
    UPDATE  r
    SET     TurnOver = (SELECT  SUM(amount)
                        FROM    tbcoudet
                        WHERE   memcode = r.memcode
                                AND expyear = (SELECT MAX(expyear)
                                               FROM   tbexpyear
                                              )
                                AND EXISTS ( SELECT itemcode
                                             FROM   tbitem
                                             WHERE  comcode = @comcode
                                                    AND SubComCode = @SubComCode
                                                    AND itemcode = tbcoudet.itemcode )
                        GROUP BY memcode
                              , expyear
                       )
    FROM    #result r
  END
  IF @SubComCode = '0'
  BEGIN
    UPDATE  r
    SET     TurnOver = (SELECT  SUM(amount)
                        FROM    tbcoudet
                        WHERE   memcode = r.memcode
                                AND expyear = (SELECT MAX(expyear)
                                               FROM   tbexpyear
                                              )
                                AND EXISTS ( SELECT itemcode
                                             FROM   tbitem
                                             WHERE  comcode = @comcode
                                                    AND itemcode = tbcoudet.itemcode )
                        GROUP BY memcode
                              , expyear
                       )
    FROM    #result r
  END

  SELECT TOP 10
          *
  FROM    #result
  WHERE   TurnOver IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY TurnOver DESC
END
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Since this is not an answer, but a new question, please search existing questions and answers and then, if you can't find a solution, create a new question.

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to create the temporary table twice in the procedure.

In the second query don't use `select ... into #result ...` but rather `insert into #result select ...` so that it doesn't try to create it again.

---

Note that the prefix `sp_` means *System Procedure*, and should not be used for regular procedures.

Comment: temp tables are automatically dropped at the end of stored procedures that create them.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I use temporary tables across procedures.

Comment: See the section [Temporary Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), first bullet point "A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished." You can use temp tables across procedures, but you have to *create* those tables in an outer scope.

Comment: thanks for replying me..now stored Procedure is working good but i am going to execute "select top 10 * from #result where TurnOver is not null order by TurnOver desc" then i get error "Invalid object name '#result'." Can you tell me how to solve this problem..please

Comment: @user1099310: It sounds like you are removing the table before selecting the result from it. You can remove it afterwards, the select doesn't have to be the last statement in the procedure.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks for the reference. I have adjusted the answer to the reality. :)