# Odd error using IF/ELSE IF statements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a temp table dependent on the value of a scenario parameter and using the following IF statement but getting the error below:

```
    IF @indexName = 'A'
        begin select top 400 * into #temp from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
    ELSE IF @indexName = 'B'
        begin select top 75 * into #temp from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
    ELSE IF @indexName = 'C'
        begin select top 300 * into #temp from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
    ELSE 
        begin select top 100 * into #temp from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
```

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 179
>   There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.
>   Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 181
>   There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.
>   Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 183
>   There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

I'm certain the IF statement works based on the @indexName variable (replacing the block statement with something simple (eg, 'select @indexName'), the program runs fine).

Any ideas about what's causing this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since only the top number of records are difference. You can try this

```
declare @num int 

SET @num = CASE @indexName 
                    WHEN 'A' THEN 400
                    WHEN 'B' THEN 75
                    WHEN 'C' THEN 300
                    ELSE  100
            END

select top (@num) * into #temp from #pretemp order by EMRev desc
```

Answer (score 12):

The SQL parser looks for all places that might create a temp table, and only allows a given temp table name to be used ONE time.  The solution is to do something like this:

```
select * into #temp from #pretemp where 1=2

IF @indexName = 'A'
    begin insert into #temp select top 400 * from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
ELSE IF @indexName = 'B'
    begin insert into #temp select top 75 * from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
ELSE IF @indexName = 'C'
    begin insert into #temp select top 300 * from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
ELSE 
    begin insert into #temp select top 100 * from #pretemp order by EMRev desc end
```

The `where 1=2` creates the table structure with zero records...  Then the if statements populate the temp table.

Cheers!

Comment: Excellent solution. I wouldn't have thought of that and would have copied the definition of #pretemp, thereby making #temp require a change when #pretemp changes (I'm guessing this is in a sproc). This is easier and makes the intent (that the temp tables have the same structure and #temp is a subset) much clearer. Very nice. :)

Comment: Very good!  I came up with an almost identical solution.  :-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245444/there-is-already-an-object-named-columntable-in-the-database#25563861  This issue also occurs with `IF .. ELSE .. CREATE TABLE #SomeTempTable`, I've mentioned a solution to that also.