# Stored Procedure: There is already an object named '#columntable' in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please see the code below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
BEGIN
    begin
    select * into #dbreviews from dbreviews
    end

    drop table #dbreviews

    begin
    select * into #dbreviews from dbreviews
    end

END
GO
```

The error I get is:

> There is already an object named `'#dbreviews'` in the database.

Questions like this: [There is already an object named '#columntable' in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245444/there-is-already-an-object-named-columntable-in-the-database) are telling me this should be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per SQL Server specification, it is not allowed. Please refer to the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.100).aspx).

> If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored
>   procedure or batch, they must have different names.

You are creating two temporary tables, with the same name `#dbreviews`. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that you use the "alter" syntax:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE
```

if you paste code in, you may need to replace "create" with "alter"... this just happened to me and is frustrating, so I hope this helps someone else.

Note:  This was my answer to a slightly different question, so I *recycled* it.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of your PROC, `#dbreviews` exists. When you run it again, it already exists. If you want to recreate every time you run the proc, use:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dbreviews') IS NOT NULL
THEN
  drop table #dbreviews
END IF

select * into #dbreviews from dbreviews
```